# Открытие/закрытие меню при наведении на чистом js

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, меню

Получилось так, что элементы меню имеют особое подчеркивание (которое можно реализовать только используя `position: rel/abs`) и элементы на `after`, а `subMenu` должно быть во всю ширину экрана и я не нашла другого выхода как реализовывать его при помощи `js`. Мое `MegaMenu` находиться после `header`. И я хочу сделать, чтобы при наведении на пункт меню с классом `menu-toggle`, `MegaMenu` менял свой `display`.

HTML - внутри определенная структура структура

```
<div class="header__mega-menu">...</div>
```

Меню, которое с классом menu-toggle

```
<nav class="header__nav">
      <ul class="header__menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu-toggle"><a href="#">Catalog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

JS - вот тут не получается. Не знаю как написать, чтобы меню показывалось при наведении на `menu-toggle` и не исчезало как только я убираю курсор с ссылки, а й отображалось когда курсор перешел в выпадающее меню, то-есть в развернутом  `MegaMenu` ???  Как объединить эти 2 события?

```
const menuItem = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-toggle');
const megaMenu = document.querySelector('.header__mega-menu');

Array.from(menuItem).forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('mouseenter', showSub);
  item.addEventListener('mouseleave', hideSub);
});

function showSub () {
  megaMenu.style.display = 'block';
}

function hideSub () {
  megaMenu.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У MouseEvent`ов есть свойство relatedTarget, которое возвращает элемент на который был переведен курсор. Это поможет если на пути между '.menu-toggle' и '.header__mega-menu' нет сторонних элементов.
Пользуясь этим свойством ваш код выглядел бы вот так:

```
function hideSub (event) {
  //relatedTarget может быть равен null
  const { relatedTarget = {}} = event;

  if (relatedTarget.className !== 'header__mega-menu') {
    megaMenu.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Comment: между элементами есть разрыв, и если даже удается перейти на header__mega-menu, то оно не закрывается, если с него убрать курсор